# Newton Series for the Digamma Function

Tags: reference-request, digamma-function

The [Wikipedia page for the digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) states that the following holds:
$$\psi(s+1) = -\gamma - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\binom{s}{k}.$$
Is there any textbook/paper where this formula is given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the result in the display immediately before the words "third Retkes identity" at the [English Wikipedia page for Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation).  It is the derivation $H_n = \dots = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1} \frac{1}{k} \binom{n}{k}$, which gives you the less obvious piece in the identity you see.